# Can't create sockets to domain

Tags: sockets, telnet, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 lts on my server.

I ran into a problem where my server.jar file couldn't create an SSL socket to prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com.

I tried "telnet prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com 2099", but it can't establish a connection.
However, "telnet prod.euw1.lol.riotgames.com 2099" runs fine on a different ubuntu 12.xx server that I ssh'd into, and it works fine on my personal computer.

And strangely, connections to other host servers with "telnet prod.na1.lol.riotgames.com 2099" or "telnet prod.eun1.lol.riotgames.com 2099" on my ubuntu 10.04 machine work just fine.

I don't know what steps to take next, I've already flushed my iptables rules to accept all incoming/outgoing traffic, and the IP address that the domain resolves to is the same across all of the computers I've tried.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? Please let me know. Otherwise we could possibly work on this together.

Comment: @user2015253 Yeah, I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: @user2015253 I got it. I tried literally everything I could on my end, and then I tried the support team out for Linode. None of that helped, and they insisted that it was my home connection (how would that even make sense?). I transferred from their Texas servers to their CA servers, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply! Maybe they blocked some big hosting centers to prevent botting or something like that. I'll try to find a hoster which allows Connections to them then. :)